# How to check if an app is using swift - IOS objc

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sdk

I have an SDK that is written completely in ObjC.
Is there a way to know if the SDK (that integrated into their app) is running on an app that uses Swift?

Comment: Why should that matter at runtime?

Comment: No, there is no way to check this, unless you provide source and the client can set certain build flags. However, I would strongly discourage from this approach. You may provide a variant for Swift and Objective-C however. Swift APIs are _far_ more powerful and provide features which are not possible with an Objective-C API. So, it's time to declare your Objective-C lib as legacy and make a new one in Swift ;)

Comment: @manasshr i'm trying to know if the app that integrated my sdk is using swift.